# How would I take what a user typed into an input field and turn it into an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple one input text box in which the user is supposed to copy what I present to them.

```
<h3 id="beginGame">Play</h3>

<h3 id="textOnScreen"></h3>

<form>
<input type="text" id="userInput" style="display: none;"></input>
<button type="button" id="nextButton" style="display: none;">Next</button>
</form>
```

I then want to take what they've typed into the text box and verify it against the currently selected index of an array called 'nutrients'.

```
    var nutrients = [
        "Vitamin B6",
        "Manganese",
        "Vitamin C",
        "Fiber",
        "Potassium",
        "Biotin",
        "Copper"

    ];
```

Originally I had the user interacting with prompts and alerts.  However, I am now trying to convert it into a pure HTML element based interface.

For instance I have a function called ask()
which in the beginning looked like this:

```
function ask() {
     userInput = prompt("Enter the following into the text field: " + nutrients[i] + ".");
}
```

But now it looks like this:

```
   function ask() {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "Enter the following into the text field: " + nutrients[i] + ".";
    }
```

The current puzzle I'm trying to unravel is my formatText() function.  This function is designed to take what a user inputs and format it to match how the values stored in the array 'nutrients' are typed, regardless of how they capitalize thier entries.  When I was using prompts I accomplished this using the following code:

```
    function formatText() {

    if (userInput === "") {
                    alert("You must enter a value");
                    ask();
                    formatText();
                }

            var answerArray = userInput.split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < answerArray.length; i++) {
                answerArray[i] = answerArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + answerArray[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
            }

            finalAnswer = answerArray.join(" ");
}
```

Which I then passed to a function called validateAnswer() which looks like this

```
 function validateAnswer() {

        if (finalAnswer === nutrients[i]) {
            alert("You are correct! " + nutrients[i]);
        } else {
            alert("That is incorrect. Please try again.");
            ask();
            formatText();
            validateAnswer();

        }
    }
```

However, now that I'm trying to use innerHTML to actually present text on the screen, and I'm using an input field to accept the users input, I can no longer use the split() method.  So I tried to alter my code slightly and turned it into this:

```
function formatText() {

    if (userInput === "") {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "You must enter a value";
        ask();
        formatText();
    }

    userInput = [];




    for (i; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        userInput[i] = userInput[i][0].toUpperCase() + userInput[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    finalAnswer = userInput.join(" ");

}
```

However, now I get this error:

Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
formatText
validateAnswer
validateAnswer
validateAnswer
validateAnswer
etc...

I realize that I have more than one issue I'm trying to work out.  However, the only one I'm trying address right now is some alternative to my formatText() function.  How would I take the users input from an input field such as this

```
<input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
```

and break it up into an array so that I can use my formatText() function?  Or would I have to completely go about it a different way?

Below I will paste the entire chuck of code I'm working on so you may see what I've done in a more linear fashion, and where it currently stands. Your help is very much appreciated.

```
function memoNutri() {
    "use strict";

    var nutrients = [
        "Vitamin B6",
        "Manganese",
        "Vitamin C",
        "Fiber",
        "Potassium",
        "Biotin",
        "Copper"

    ],
        finalAnswer, i = 0,
        userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');




    //This function reveals certain elements while hiding others
    function showHide(show, show2, hide) {

        document.getElementById(show).style.display = 'block';

        document.getElementById(show2).style.display = 'block';

        document.getElementById(hide).style.display = 'none';

    }


    showHide("userInput", "nextButton",
        "beginGame");


    //This function is responsible for giving the user instructions
    function ask() {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "Enter the following into the text field: " + nutrients[i] + ".";
    }



    //This function takes the users input and formats it to match the values stored in the array
    function formatText() {

        if (userInput === "") {
            document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "You must enter a value";
            ask();
            formatText();
        }

        userInput = [];




        for (i; i < userInput.length; i++) {
            userInput[i] = userInput[i][0].toUpperCase() + userInput[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }

        finalAnswer = userInput.join(" ");

    }


    //This function checks the users answer against the value stored in the array
    function validateAnswer() {

        if (finalAnswer === nutrients[i]) {
            document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "You are correct! " + nutrients[i];
        } else {
            document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "That is incorrect. Please try again.";
            ask();
            formatText();
            validateAnswer();

        }
    }




    //This code is the execution portion of the function memoNutri
    for (i; i < nutrients.length; i++) {

        ask();

        formatText();

        validateAnswer();

    }
}





var beginGame = document.getElementById('beginGame');
beginGame.onclick = memoNutri;
```

Comment: You need to simplify this question. From the heading it sounds like you want to split a string into an array, which is simple to do.

Comment: He wants to validate each one separately. BTW, this "finalAnswer === nutrients[i]" checks to see if they are stored in the same memory location, you want == not ===

Comment: You also need to look into doing onload if you're going to use document.getElementById('beginGame') and assign an onclick event to it like that. The javascript may load before the element with that ID does, which will make it so the onclick never attaches.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Perhaps I'm over complicating the question.  I will admit I am a beginner at this.  This is my atempt to take what I've learned and actually build something.  So it's likely that I'm not seeing something obvious.  I guess what I'm trying to get at is I found it easy to manipulate a users input when it came to a prompt, but it's not so clear to me how to grab the users input and manipulate it from an input.  Radio buttons and the like wouldn't work only because I actually want the user to type something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I have now tested this code and fixed my typos. It works up until the end of your array where it should break. You can figure out that part yourself I imagine.

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/cXBzA/

You have over complicated this quite a bit.

All the HTML you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="./scripts/nutrient.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="confirm"></p>
    <p id="output-nutrient"></p>
    <input type="text" id="input-nutrient">
    <input type="button" id="check-answer" value="Check Answer">
    <div id="js-memory" data=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

All the Javascript you need (nutrient.js):

```
var nutrients = ["Vitamin B6", "Manganese", "Vitamin C", "Fiber", "Potassium", "Biotin", "Copper"];

var onLoad = function () {
    document.getElementById("check-answer").onclick = checkAnswer;
    document.getElementById("output-nutrient").innerHTML = nutrients[0];
    document.getElementById("js-memory").setAttribute("data", "0");
};

var checkAnswer = function() {
    var inputNutrient = document.getElementById("input-nutrient").value;
    var outputIndex = document.getElementById("js-memory").getAttribute("data");
    outputIndex = parseInt(outputIndex);
    if(inputNutrient == nutrients[outputIndex]) {
        outputIndex += 1;
        document.getElementById("output-nutrient").innerHTML = nutrients[outputIndex];
        document.getElementById("js-memory").setAttribute("data", outputIndex);
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Correct!";
        document.getElementById("input-nutrient").value = "";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("confirm").innerHTML = "Try Again!";
    }
};

if(!window.onload) {
    window.onload = function() {
        onLoad();
    };
}
else {
    var oldWindowLoadFunction = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        oldWindowLoadFunction();
        onLoad();
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the time you took to help me...I will have to take some time to analyze and soak in what you have written here.  I will get back to you, perhaps a bit later, on how it's going

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean by recursive as you've stated in your other comments.  However, I'm still stumped as to why it works perfectly when prompts are used yet now with innerHTML and text boxes it perpetually loops.  I don't expect you to be able to answer all of my questions and you've been very helpful thus far, but if you do have any insight into that I would love to know. This is the original (working perfectly) http://jsfiddle.net/MddHtt13/qxG49/31/ Use it, test it. I haven't tested your code just yet, I just wanted to show you that it did work before I tried to hook it to HTML elements.

Comment: Alright I've at least gone to jsfiddle and used your code.  It does work almost perfectly.  However it is still case sensitive.  Funny enough that was actually what this whole post was about.  My function formatText() takes care of that.  You could enter fiber, fiBer, FiBer etc...it wouldn't matter because it would be technically correct...I've taken the users answer and formatted it to match how it it looks in the array. That way no matter how it's capitalized it will be correct.  What I found was that once I moved away from prompts I could no longer call the split method.

Comment: All you have to do is call .toLowerCase() on both the array value and the input value when comparing them. Then it will no longer be case sensitive. Don't make it more complicated than that.

Comment: It is working using prompts because the prompt pauses the execution of the javascript while it is open. When they enter text and press ok it unpauses and proceeds through the loop. You should not design around this, it is a side effect, not a feature, of prompts.

Comment: @ sage88 Ah, I see what you're saying.  I still have a lot to learn, but with people like you willing to help me work through my confusion I will get there.  I appreciate all the time you've spent on this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's one of the issues you're facing. Your stack overflow is coming from your recursive function calls. These two functions call themselves:

```
function formatText() {

    if (userInput === "") {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "You must enter a value";
        ask();
        formatText();
    }
```

And

```
function validateAnswer() {

    if (finalAnswer === nutrients[i]) {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "You are correct! " + nutrients[i];
    } else {
        document.getElementById('textOnScreen').innerHTML = "That is incorrect. Please try again.";
        ask();
        formatText();
        validateAnswer();

    }
}
```

You need to restructure so that these functions are called only when a user inputs a new answer. Otherwise, when they are called the first time, they will just loop.

Comment: You're probably correct.  Although, I will say that when I was using prompts instead of innerHTML and text boxes these functions worked as I had intended them.  I will have to do some thinking and read a bit more about recursive function calls.

Comment: You really don't need to do this recursively. You shouldn't actually.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, I don't quite understand.  Would you have a suggestion on how to do it differently? My initial logic was...if the user doesn't make the proper entry then it would run through the exact same series of functions until they got it correct and bypassed that all together.

Comment: You need to wait for them to input new information before running the function again. Currently it checks the users input in a loop forever if they input the wrong answer. As your error indicates, this is causing your system to run out of memory.

Comment: A recursive function is one that calls itself. This situation is not one where a recursive function should be used. You should output correct when they answer correctly, or incorrect when they answer incorrectly. Then just wait for them to submit again and the function will run again. Right now it runs again (and again, and again...) without the user ever entering new information.